# Updating value in json with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a cart using javascript and jquery. 
If I will press search button table will show with the matched search.
Following is the code.

```
 obj.forEach(item => {
    if (item.Name.includes(inputValue) && inputValue != "") {
        trSecond = document.createElement("tr");
        tdName = document.createElement("td");
        tdCategory = document.createElement("td");
        tdMRP = document.createElement("td");
        tdQuantity = document.createElement("td");

        txtNameData = document.createTextNode(item.Name);
        txtCategoryData = document.createTextNode(item.Catagory);
        txtMRPData = document.createTextNode(item.MRP);
        txtQuantityData = document.createElement("Input");
        txtQuantityData.setAttribute("type", "number");
        txtQuantityData.setAttribute("value", "1");
        txtQuantityData.setAttribute("id", "inputQuantity");

        tdName.appendChild(txtNameData);
        tdCategory.appendChild(txtCategoryData);
        tdMRP.appendChild(txtMRPData);
        tdQuantity.appendChild(txtQuantityData);

        trSecond.appendChild(tdCategory);
        trSecond.appendChild(tdName);
        trSecond.appendChild(tdMRP);
        trSecond.appendChild(tdQuantity);
        document.getElementById("searchResult").appendChild(trSecond);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Not found");
    }
});
```

Now I want the number I input here in quantity will change my object array value quantity and I want to access it in another  function with the press of button Add to Cart.How should I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an eventlistener to `txtQuantityData`

```
txtQuantityData.addEventListener('change', () => {
  // update your object value here ( I can't provide an example because you omitted the object from the code in your question)
  // e.g.:
  // item.amount = txtQuantityData.getAttribute('value');
});
```

Same approach on adding to cart.

Comment: thanks it is updating but same value for all amount even if i select different amount.

Comment: @BhaskarJoshi And if you use `txtQuantityData.value`. If I recall this right `txtQuantityData.getAttribute('value');` would always output the initial value. Weird, right?

Comment: yeah...but i set attribute id by( item.name) and after that it is returning unique value.Thanks for your help